# Azure Monitor Query Error path does not exist c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to retrieve information from Application Insights using an `Azure.Monitor.Query` in C#:

```
string workspaceId = "defaultworkspace-...-eus";

var client = new LogsQueryClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

try
{
     Response<LogsQueryResult> response = await client.QueryWorkspaceAsync(workspaceId,
                "AppEvents | count", QueryTimeRange.All);

     LogsTable table = response.Value.Table;

     foreach (var row in table.Rows)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(row);
     }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     log.LogInformation(e.Message);
 }
```

But it's no working and I get the following error:

> Azure.RequestFailedException: 'The requested path does not exist
> Status: 404 (Not Found)
> ErrorCode: PathNotFoundError

I want to retrieve all customEvents from insights, maybe some configuration in azure portal is needed?

Comment: What is you URL?  Error indicates the URL + ROUTE does not exist.  The route is the path.

Comment: This typically happens when the workspaceId is not correct. Please make sure that you use the **id, not the name** of the workspace!

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have custom event logs when you run the query `customEvents` in application insight log section.
  check the below:

[image]

- Copy the `workspaceId`  from the `application insights=>Overview=> workspace=>workspaceId`.

[image]

By using the below code and my workspaceId  I am able to retrieve the customEvents from the application insights successfully.

**Code:**

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string workspaceId = "your-workspace-id";
        string query = "union * | take 10"; 

        var client = new LogsQueryClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

        try
        {
            Response<LogsQueryResult> response = await client.QueryWorkspaceAsync(workspaceId, query, QueryTimeRange.All);

            LogsTable table = response.Value.Table;

            foreach (var row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var column in table.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{column.Name}: {row[column.Name]}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]